# CString or char array which one is better in terms of memory

Tags: c++, memory, char, cstring

I read somewhere that usage of CString is costly. Can you calrify it with an example. Also among CString and char array, which is better in terms of memory.

Comment: CString is from MFC framework. std::string is from c++ standard. They are library classes for managing strings in memory. Unless you are very particular about memory use the classes as they provide many features and you don't have to worry about out of bounds checks, etc. std string will provide you code portability. In terms of memory char array is good however in the long run utility classes like std string are benificial for managing stuff

Comment: Why not [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)?

Comment: Which do you find easier to program? That should be your main concern. Computers have a lot of memory and unless you're programming something quite exceptional the memory used by strings is so small that it's pretty much irrelevant. However, buggy code caused by badly written string handling is very common and very relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CString in addition to array of chars (or wide chars) contains string size, allocated buffer size, and reference counter (serving additionally as a lock flag). The buffer containing the array of chars may be significantly larger than the string it contains -- it allows to reduce the number of time-costly allocation calls. In addition, when the CString is set to be zero-sized, it still contains two wchar characters.

Naturally, when you compare the size of CString with the size of corresponding C-style array, the array will be smaller. However, if you want to manipulate your string as extensively as CString allows, you will eventually define your own variables for string size, buffer size and sometimes refcounter and/or guard flags. Indeed, you need to store your string size to avoid calling strlen each time you need it. You need to store separately your buffer size if you allow your buffer to be larger than the string length, and avoid calling reallocs each time you add to or subtract from the string. And so on -- you trade some small size increase for significant increases in speed, safety and functionality.

So, the answer depends on what you are going to do with the string. Suppose you want a string to store the name of your class for logging -- there a C-style string (const and static) will do fine. If you need a string to manipulate and use it extensively with MFC or ATL-related classes, use CString family types. If you need to manipulate string in the "engine" parts of your application that are isolated from its interface, and may be converted to other platforms, use std::string or write your own string type to suit your particular needs (this can be really useful when you write the "glue" code to place between the interface and the engine, otherwise std::string is preferable).

Answer (score 0):

CString is from MFC framework specific to windows. std::string is from c++ standard. They are library classes for managing strings in memory. std::string will provide you code portability across platforms.

Using raw array is always good for memory however one has to do operations on strings and it becomes difficult with raw array, consider out of bounds check, get the string length, copy the array or change the size because the string may grow, deleting the array, etc. For all these problem string utility class are good wrapper. The string class will keep the actual string in heap and you have the overhead of the string class itself. However that will provide you functionality to mange the string memory which anyway you have to write by hand.

Prefer std::string if you can, if not, use CString.

Answer (score 0):

In almost all cases I encourage novice programmers to use std::string or CString(*). First they will do significantly less errors. I have seen many buffer overruns, memory invalidation or memory leaks, because of erroneous use of C arrays.

So which is more efficient, CString / std::string or raw character arrays? Memory wise, generally speaking, all CString ans std::string have more is one integer for the size. The question is does it matter?

So which is more efficient in terms of performance? Well it depends on what you are doing with it and how you are using your C-arrays. But passing CString or std::string arround can be computationally more efficient than C-arrays. The problem with C-arrays is that you can't be sure of who owns the memory and what type (heap/stack/literal) it is. Defensive programming results in more copies of arrays, you know, just to be sure that the memory you hold will be valid for the entire duration of when it is needed.

Why is std::string or CString more efficient than C-arrays, if they are passed around by value? This is a bit more complicated and for totally different reasons. For CString, this is simple, it implemented as a COW (copy on write) object. So when you have 5 objects that originate for one CString, it will not use more memory that one, until you start to make change on one object. std::string has stricter requirements and thus it is not allowed to share memory with other std:: string objects. But if you have a newer compiler, std::string should implement the move semantic and thus returning a string from a function will only result in a copy of the pointer not reallocation.

There are very few cases where raw C arrays are good and practical idea.

*) If you are already programming against MFC, why not just use CString.